# How to assign different background colors for the button?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to set different colors for the button.For example When i click the button it should display multiple colors from that i should choose one and that color should be applied for the button.How can i do it?need your suggestion friends
Thank you in advance

Comment: colors are static one or dynamic ??

Comment: There are several options are availabele. For eg. you can open a layot containing color boxes. take them as button and apply their Onclick on which set appropriate hashcode(color code) to button.

Comment: static type how can i do it

Comment: You can look for a color picker library

Comment: Am a beginner.kindly tell me how to do it?

Comment: Can you upload mockup view for requirement. Due to under reputations you can't upload image . just share your uploaded link

Comment: @vimal kumar R  see my ans...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom drawable XML and set this button background.

`android:background="@drawble/your XML"`

You can set color when button press and normal state .Try this way , I hope it will helps you .

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions,But what i need is while clicking the button it should display multiple colors The user should can any color and it should be applied to the button .This is the feature i need

Comment: Oh..I think you should use color picker

Comment: Please search android color picker library .

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   void onClick(View v) {
   // create the color picker dialog and display it.
      ColorPickerDialog cDialog = new ColorPickerDialog(v.getContext(),new OnColorChangedListener()     
      {
          void colorChanged(int color) {
           mSelectedColor = color;
          }

     }),initialColor);

   cDialog.show();

   }
});
```

'mSelectedColor' will be the color you apply to the button.

Answer (score 0):

try like this hope work for you..

`colorDialog()` is call on click listener of your button which you want to show color option and `body_view` id is replace with your button id.

colorDialog():-

```
private void colorDialog()
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(CreateNewNote.this);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_lay, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateNewNote.this);

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Select Color");
    alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_toast);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);

    Button btncol1=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.col1);
    Button btncol2=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.col2);
    Button btncol3=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.col3);
    Button btncol4=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.col4);
    Button btncol5=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.col5);
    Button btncol6=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.col6);

    final AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();

    title_lay=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.toplayout);
    body_view=(View)findViewById(R.id.body);


    btncol1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            body_view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.body_color1);
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });

    btncol2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            body_view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.body_color2);
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });
    btncol3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            body_view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.body_color3);
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });
    btncol4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            body_view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.body_color4);
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });
    btncol5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            body_view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.body_color5);
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });
    btncol6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            body_view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.body_color6);
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

color_lay.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/col1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#F8BBD0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/col2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFCCBC" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/col3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#E1BEE7" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/col4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#BBDEFB" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/col5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#C8E6C9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/col6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFF9C4" />

</LinearLayout>
```